# How to combine Cygwin and Matlab to run this toolbox?

Tags: matlab, cygwin

I want to run this toolbox from this website: http://www.princeton.edu/~fpereira/searchmight/. I choose to download “Linux(64 bit)” . I am not familiar with Linux and also I do not know how to combine Cygwin and Matlab to run this toolbox (there are C code and Mex file in the toolbox). Can anyone tell me how to run this toolbox by combining Cygwin and Matlab? Thanks a lot!

If I Install a Virtual Machine and Ubuntu on Windows 7, is that OK for running this toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to do this with Cygwin. I think you'll need to install Linux or a Linux VM in order to run that code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work on Windows at all. Cygwin includes libraries that help you compile the source code for Linux programs to run on Windows, but it cannot run Linux binaries.

You have several options here:

- Use a Linux machine or a Mac
- Install a Linux VM on your Windows machine
- Ask the authors for the source code and compile it yourself on windows

Comment: ,the author does not have the source code for windows system.Can you tell me how to install Linux VM on my windows system? Does it need large space?

Comment: Sorry, that is somewhat outside my area of expertise. :)

Comment: If I Install a Virtual Machine and Ubuntu on Windows 7, is that OK for running this toolbox?

Comment: Should be. You would also have to install MATLAB under the Ubuntu VM.

Comment: WOW! That means there are 2 Matlab in my computer.

Comment: Is it any more amazing than having two different operating systems in your computer?  If it helps, you can think of the VM as a whole separate computer. :)

Comment: If I have to install Matlab under the Ubuntu VM, How many RAM should be allocated to the Virtual Machine? Is 512MB enough?

Comment: Depends on how much RAM you have to begin with.  I would give it at least 4GB, assuming that you have a 64-bit machine.

Comment: ,My RAM is 600GB, 64bit, OK, I give it 4GB

Comment: I am guessing the 600GB is your hard disk, not RAM. In that case you should allocate more disk space for the VM. I would use 100GB if you can spare it.  You will need disk space for the Ubuntu OS itself, for the MATLAB install, and for your data.

Comment: there are two steps need to choose the amount of space.1)the amount of memory allocated to the Virtual Machine 2)select the size of the virtual hard drive in megabytes.The size is the limit on the amount of file data that a virtual machine will be able to store on the hard drive. The 4GB, you mean for the second one?

Comment: Please take a look at this :http://www.instructables.com/id/Introduction-38/step2/Configuring-a-New-Virtual-Machine/ It mentions 512MB and 8GB for different steps. Is it enough for my case?

Comment: Sorry, there is only so much time I can spend on this. I think you are well on your way to figuring this out.

Comment: the 100GB you mentioned is to replace the 8GB, am I right?